# What's the most efficient way to generate multiple images from the same source? C# / Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I'm creating an application that accepts large images from an IP Camera to be displayed on a website. Currently the images are 4K resolution with a size range from anywhere between 1MB to 3MB.

These images are to be displayed into a gallery.

For this i need only two images. A 250 x 160 thumbnail and a larger image for the light-box (I've chosen 1280 x 720). However it might be more efficient to get four images at the same time for other parts of the site.

My library of choice is currently SixLabors.ImageSharp.

The question is, is the below code an efficient way to generate images from one image without the risk of Memory Leaks or other pitfalls?

This code will be reworked into an AzureFunction (BlobTrigger) eventually.

```
public async Task GenerateThumbnails(Stream source, ImageSizes[] sizes)
        {
            //Test data
            sizes = new ImageSizes[] { new ImageSizes { Name ="720p", Height=720, Width=1280 },
                                       new ImageSizes { Name ="1080p", Height=1080, Width=1920 },
                                       new ImageSizes { Name ="gallery", Height=160, Width=250 },
                                       new ImageSizes { Name ="thumb", Height=30, Width=30 }};

            List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>(sizes.Length);

            foreach (var size in sizes)
            {
                allTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

                    using (Image rawImage = Image.Load(source))
                    {
                        rawImage.Mutate(x => x.Resize(size.Width, size.Height));
                        rawImage.Save(outputStream, new JpegEncoder() { Quality = 40 });                        
                    }

                    using (var fileStream = outputStream)
                    {
                        //Do something here. Upload to Azure Blob / container or save to disk etc...
                        //blob.UploadFromStream(outputStream);
                    }
                }));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

            //Do something else;
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like something ImageSharp.Web would help with.

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to not make the bulk of the work in ASP.Net. [ASP.Net already has serious memory issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i) from running potentially 100 requests per CPU *Core* in paralell. About the last thing you want to do, is add more to it's job list. Especially a memory hog like Image manipulation.

I would do the minimal amount I would need to do in ASP.Net - main image and thumbnail. Preparations for the other parts? Those can be moved out into a Background Process. A Deamon that goes of the list sand finds those entries where those other formats are missing.

Actually YouTube uses such a design. On Upload, it will do the minimal work nessesary. Propably even only saving the raw binary. It will do the different resolution/quality versions of each Video one after the other, from weakest to highest.

Note taht another importan question is how you stored those blobs in/with a Database. For that, there is [one article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) I can link you too.